# When i am trying to Create a emulator in AVD Manager of Eclipse(Windows XP) its showing "Error: null" in Android console

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been working in my Windows XP pc for last few weeks with
android using Eclipse IDE
I updated some Updates in Eclipse and also for Android SDK

Then Again when i am trying to create the emulator it was saying the
error as below
in Android Console Window

[2011-10-03 16:14:39 - SDK Manager] Error: null

I cant find any solution upto my knowledge .. i am unable to resolve this
issue in some blogs and stackoverflow too
can any one suggest like this issue or steps to resolve this

With Regards

Pradeepraj N

Comment: did you create a new virtual device after the update or you are trying to start the old one(before the update)?

Comment: I am trying to create a new one.. clearing all the old ones..

Comment: also I tried reinstalling the Eclipse IDE and Android Developer Tools  , I think the problem is with in the android SDK.. or System settings

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your emulator.exe file is moved from ~\~\android-sdk\tools to ~\~\android-sdk\platform-tools folder
Please check the folder if you have that.
If the file is there then while creating the AVD through eclipse give the correct path where the AVD is there.

Comment: emulator.exe is loaded in the path C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ as u suggested not mislocated.. but it is reporting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the link for the clear instructions:
http://prasildas.blogspot.com/2011/09/setting-up-for-android.html